# laravel app class not found after deployment

Tags: class, laravel-5, model, web-deployment, shared-hosting

*Please, Be indulgent, this is my first question here... ;)*

After deploying a Laravel 5.4 site on a shared server, the following error appears:

> Class 'App\Langue' not found

And it appears for each of my class. Everything is functional except the pages where I call a class.

#### Here is my code:

One of my Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use App\Langue;
use App\Formation;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class FormationController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        $langueId = Langue::where('raccourci', App::getLocale())
                          ->select('id')
                          ->first();

...}
```

One of my class (Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use App;

class langue extends Model
{
    public function coaches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Coach');
    }


    public static function keepOldLanguage() {
        Session::put('oldLanguage', App::getLocale());
    }
}
```

#### Here is the tree view of my files

- mydomain

  - app
  - public_html
  - vendor
  - ...

#### Here's what I've tried so far:

1. php composer.phar clearcache
2. php composer.phar dump-autoload (with and without -o)
3. php composer.phar update
4. php composer.phar install
5. change uppercase and lowercase for my class
6. Check if my class is in file autoload_classmap.php (and Yes it is:
   'App\langue' => $baseDir . '/app/langue.php', )
7. and many other things...

Local OS: Windows 10

Maybe it's just a detail, but please, help me

*PS1: As you may have noticed, this is the first time I have deployed a site in Laravel.

PS2: if information is missing, please ask for it...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think u use lower case in model language and upper case in controller Language check it

Comment: Thanks RamAnji! That is true! I appreciate !! :D